# Will standing wave form between two sources?

Tags: waves

If we have two coherent sources generating waves of the same amplitude, on the line joining the two sources, the waves are traveling in opposite directions. Will a standing wave form?

For example, two coherent sources are placed $3\lambda$ apart generating coherent waves.
Taking the source 1 as the origin.
[image]

$y_1=A\sin(kx-\omega t)$

$y_2=A\sin(kx+\omega t-6\pi)$

Principle of superposition tells us that the resultant wave in the region between the sources is

$y_1+y_2 = 2A\sin(kx-3\pi)\cos(\omega t-3\pi)$ which is the equation for a standing wave

The above equation indicates that at $x=0.25\lambda$, there is an anti-node found.
However, if we consider the path difference at $x=0.25\lambda$, it should be $2.5\lambda$, i.e. destructive interference occurs. What is wrong in the above calculation?

Comment: at $x=0.25\lambda$, is it $0.25\lambda$ away from source 1 and $2.75\lambda$ away from source 2? So, the path difference at that point should be $2.75\lambda-0.25\lambda=2.5\lambda$?

Comment: I think you forgot a "minus sign" when you looked at the phase of both waves at that location.   BTW, throw away the   $-6\pi$ , since any multiple of $2\pi$ is irrelevant

Comment: that's how strings under tension work in musical instruments

Comment: @fraxinus Well, string instruments have standing waves, but the endpoints are not the source of energy

Answer (score 3):

Especially with such simple equations it is instructive to plot them and check the physics and the result graphically. By putting a source at $x=3\lambda$ the following graphics displays the wave at a given time $t=t_0$:

[image]

Note that this is *not* just a sine wave. Instead these are two sine waves which are "clued" together at their origin $x=3\lambda$. The left hand side and the right hand side  "move together", because they have the same origin. They are like mirror images from each another (w.r.t. the source position $x=3\lambda$).

Putting the two waves together we obtain

[image]

Thus, the graphic confirms that we have a node at $x=0.25\lambda$. However, as MarcoCiafa pointed out this depends on the relative phase of the two waves. I assume that the two sources, which generate the two waves, are in-phase (=phase difference is zero).

**"Math" argument**:

- Assuming that both waves move with such a phase that the amplitude is zero @ $t=0s$ and increases at $t>0s$, we have a constructive interference at the mid-point $x = 1.5\lambda$.
- The period of constructive interference is $\Delta x = \lambda/2$. A picture to explain this fact is that a sine wave has a max and a min within one period $\lambda$, and each of these extrema become one anti-node. Hence, anti-nodes (extrema) at
  $x_{extrem} = x(n) = (1.5 + 0.5 \, n)\lambda = \{0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, \ldots\}\lambda$.
- Between two anti-nodes must lie one node (destructive interference). Hence, the period for destructive interference is the same, $\Delta x = \lambda/2$, but shifted by $\lambda/4$. Hence,
  $x_{node}(n) = x(n) + \lambda/4 
  = \{0.25, 0.75, 1.25, 1.75, \ldots\}\lambda$.

Answer (score 1):

I think I made the same mistake you did. I always used cosines to write waves and I had never a problem like this one before because of that.

If you are working with sines, and you add no phase to any wave, at $t=0$, both sines will be on phase ("mathematically"). But, both sources being on phase ("physically") means that both waves should be the reflection of the other wrt $x=1,5\lambda$. So, when using sines, you should add a phase of $\pi$ to one of them.

This happens with sines and not with cosines because of the parity of the function.
From the source, at $t=0$ the sine is anti-symmetric, when reflecting it we should add a minus (or $\pm\pi$).

Answer (score -3):

The $2A \sin(kx – 3\pi)$ gives the amplitude of the standing wave.  It will be zero at each node (every half wavelength) where the sin function  is zero.
$(2πx/\lambda – 3\pi)  =  (2x/\lambda-3)π = nπ$  where $n$ is an integer $(-3,-2,\ldots)$.

Comment: This doesn't really explain anything